# Extracting Duplicates from two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find duplicates in two separate columns and extract only those that have duplicates in both of these columns to another worksheet. I want to compare these columns to themselves and find duplicates within the same column. Any advice about how to go about this. 
One column contains currency and another contains text. I added apicture for clarification,but this is is what I have tried so far:

```
Sub match()
Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
    wstOutput As Worksheet
Dim rngMyData As Range, _
    helperRng As Range

Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")

With wstSource
    Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:AC" & .Range("T" & .Rows.Count) & .Range(Left("N", 4) & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
End With
Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)

With helperRng
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(C20,RC20)>1,"""",1)"
    .Value = .Value
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(2, 1)
    .ClearContents
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is the column's name which contain currency and what is the column's names which contains text ?

Comment: The column with currency is column T and the Column with text is column N and I am looking to only match the first four letters in column N. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: Hope my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184972/11167163)  is working as excepted, do not hesitate to give me feedbacks so i can improve my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57184972/11167163)